# What do you call bags for sorting travel stuff?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call those small bags that are used for sorting things inside a travel bag? Usually used for toiletries, socks, underwear etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *[ditty bag](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ditty_bag)* is "A small bag used to carry one's personal effects or toiletries while traveling."  When camping, a ditty bag may be a *[stuff sack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuff_sack)*, so-called not because you put stuff into it, but because of how it is put in: stuffed in.  That is, a ditty bag looks like a much smaller version of a sleeping bag's stuff sack, or of a sail's stuff sack.  You can also get ditty bags made from [recycled sails](http://www.etsy.com/listing/71450382/recycled-sail-stuff-sack-ditty-bag-one).

Another term sometimes used is *mesh bag*, referring to a bag made of mesh.

***Edit:*** In my experience, *ditty bag* also applies to small zippered pocket-size bags, shaped like small [sports bags](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gbv=2&tbm=isch&q=small+sports+bags&revid=883187118&sa=X&ei=VoQAT5aaH-aniAKgw6jBDg&ved=0CD4Q1QIoAA&biw=888&bih=575) or holdalls.  Among [ditty bag pictures](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=888&bih=575&q=ditty+bag&gbv=2&oq=ditty+bag&aq=f&aqi=g2g-m2g-S6&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5877l10611l0l11537l9l9l0l0l0l0l265l1791l0.4.5l9l0), 
the stuff-sack type is most common, but rectangular (sports-bag shaped) zipper-top bags appear too, without the strap handles that appear on larger sports bags.

Note, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holdall) suggests that understood meaning of *holdall* varies regionally, mentioning different usages in American, British, and Indian English, and suggests that usage of *gym bag* varies between American and British English.  That is, an AE gym bag is (quoting Wikipedia) "a large bag made of cloth or leather typically with a rectangular base and a zippered opening at the top" and evidently a BE gym bag may instead be a stuff sack or [duffel bag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffel_bag).

Comment: +1 Haven't heard [ditty bag](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zsrfAAAAMAAJ&q=%22ditty+bag%22&dq=%22ditty+bag%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0V__TpeCL4KnhAfy6NjAAQ&redir_esc=y) in donkey's years! Apparently dervived from *deft (proper)* and/or *dight (dress),* it was originally more likely to be a sailor's "minimalist sewing box" that he used to smarten up his clothes before going on shore-leave.

Comment: So [this](https://www.mountainmailorder.co.za/images/uploads/Sea%20to%20Summit/ATLTB_lg.jpg) would be a ditty bag, not a stuff sack, right?

Comment: @rlesko Correct, those small zipper bags, shaped like tiny sports bags, are ditty bags but not stuff sacks.  See edit.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Unfortunately I still can't find the model I was looking for since the manufacturer obviously doesn't use any of those terms for their product. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about a separate, small case, I would call it a ***[toiletry bag](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=toiletry%20bag#q=toiletry%20bag&hl=en&prmd=imvns&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=Q1r_TvnpA4zNtgfbhLDQBg&ved=0CLoBEK0E&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=2279860aca39e76e&biw=1600&bih=785)***.

If they are integrated into the luggage itself, they are ***compartments***, or maybe *sections*.

Comment: I've also heard and used *toilet bag*.